# How to specify key name for belongsTo association when saving object?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got Post and Comment models:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  post: DS.belongsTo('post')
})
```

When I create a new comment and save it:

```
var comment = this.store.createRecord('comment');
comment.set('post', post);
comment.save();
```

it makes request with `post: 1` data inside the request. How to change it to make request with `post_id: 1` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is likely because you are using the default Ember data adapter which is the RESTAdapter.

The RESTAdapter has different conventions than the standard ActiveModel::Serializer conventions which is why it would be sending `post: 1` instead of `post_id: 1`

Try switching your default adapter to the ActiveModelAdapter

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
   namespace: 'api'
})
```

Doc can be found here http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelAdapter.html